# How to package separately located files into a same folder structure?

Tags: zip

When I use zip to pack files from different locations, like:

`zip pack.zip /home/jack/jack.txt /home/jim/jim.txt`

The files would be stored in "pack.zip" as the following structure:

```
./home/jack/jack.txt
./home/jim/jim.txt
```

But this is not what I expected. I just hope the files be stored in the root of the zip file like:

```
./jack.txt
./jim.txt
```

What should I do?

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/q/963270/963

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-j` option to zip to remove (junk) the paths:

> -j
>      --junk-paths
>           Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not store directory names. By default, zip will store the full path (relative to the current directory).

#### Example

For example, suppose that we have these files:

```
$ ls */
a/:
file

b/:
file2
```

And we zip them with `-j`:

```
$ zip -j new.zip */*
  adding: file (stored 0%)
  adding: file2 (stored 0%)
```

They are stored *without* paths:

```
$ unzip -l new.zip
Archive:  new.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name ("^" ==> case
---------  ---------- -----   ----   conversion)
        0  2014-10-21 22:15   file
        0  2014-10-21 22:14   file2
---------                     -------
        0                     2 files
```

#### Files with same basename will generate an error

Note that, with `-j`, if two files from different paths have the same name, it is an error:

```
$ zip -j new2.zip */*
        zip warning:   first full name: a/file
                      second full name: b/file
                     name in zip file repeated: file
                     this may be a result of using -j

zip error: Invalid command arguments (cannot repeat names in zip file)
```

Comment: `zip -r -j zip.file dir` will work too.

Answer (score 1):

The zip utility has the option `--junk-path` for that:

```
$ zip --junk-path pack.zip home/jack/jack.txt home/jim/jim.txt
  adding: jack.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: jim.txt (stored 0%)
$ unzip -l pack.zip 
Archive:  pack.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2014-10-22 07:12   jack.txt
        0  2014-10-22 07:12   jim.txt
---------                     -------
        0                     2 files
```