# Unix zip command junk-paths flag not working on same file names

Tags: bash, shell-script, zip

I have the following file structure:

```
cwd/
    ---dir1
       ---file_name1
       ---some_file_name
    ---dir2
       ---file_name1
       ---some_other_file_name
    ---some_file
```

I want to get zip file such that when I unzip I get `cwd` directory and NOT `pwd` directory. So [according to the man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) I need to use `-j` flag. But when I use him in this case (OS X mac unix) I got error regarding the issue I have in 2 different directories same file name (`file_name1` in the example).

```
zip error: Invalid command arguments (cannot repeat names in zip file).
first full name...
second full name...
this my be a result of using -j
```

[According to this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163514/how-to-package-separately-located-files-into-a-same-folder-structure) it seems nothing can be done and this is how `zip -j` works.
How can I still achieve the requirement of compressing the zip without the default `pwd` file structure? (I cannot rename the files - there is a reason why from the beginning I use zip via shell etc...).

Thanks,

Comment: I don't quote understand your question. Of course you cannot store two files with the same name into a zip. What is the result you're trying to achieve, how should the zip look like?

Comment: @cbley Exactly as if I used Microsoft Windows Explorer and right clicked on the folder called cwd and select comprees to zip - I get cwd.zip file, containing in the root dir1, dir2 and some_file, and inside dir1 and dir2 their files. Right now I get cwd.zip but when I unzip it I get pwd structure until I cd to actually needed files - this is redundant.

Comment: tar archives support files with the same name

Answer (score 1):

So, you don't want to junk the paths, but just ignore the top-level directory?

```
 cd cwd ; zip -r ../cwd.zip .
```

Comment: Not it's not working. When I unzip the file cwd.zip I get for example: users/name/documents/cwd/files... I need when I unzip to get cwd/files. When I do it on windows ain't problem that in 2 different dirs same file name

Comment: I think -j flag is the general solution for that but according to the link in the original question it struggles with case of 2 same file names in different dirs, and some creative solution needed

Comment: You probably did something wrong. `-j` is definitely _not_ what you want. When I execute `zip -r ../cwd.zip .` the created zip file contains `dir1`, `dir2` and `some_file` in the root, and `file_name1` in each of `dir` and `dir2`. Maybe you did something wrong when unzipping? How do you unzip?

Comment: Thanks, I use mac and double click on the file and the program that performing the unzip is rar extractor free. The result is not surprise - it's exactly as documented in the man about zip. the unzip dir starts with pwd and after several cd I get to cwd and inside all the files. in order to ignore it exist -j flag. please see the links I provided in the question. Thanks,

Comment: Have you installed the unzip program? Look at the output of `unzip -l cwd.zip`. Amend your question with the output and tell us what you expected instead in case this is wrong.

Comment: cbley I get /users/name/.../cwd/dir1 (all the pwd...). I want it to start from /cwd/dir1 etc.

Comment: Do you have, by chance, the `ZIPOPTS` environment variable defined? If so, does it include the `-jj` option? Which version of zip do you have installed?

Comment: cbley zip3.0 and ain't such flag -jj

Comment: Sorry, but I fear that I still don't fully understand what _exactly_ you're doing and what you're after. Could you perhaps make a screencast and upload that to somewhere? I think otherwise it's impossible to help you further.

Comment: It's easy - u have in unix like os /Users/user/.../dir1 inside dir1 place single dir2 with single file1. now cd to dir1 and execute `zip -r dir2.zip dir2`. The result is zip file called dir2.zip. open in in finder or similar and double click to unzip (in UI methods not shell). The result will be unzipped folder /Users/user/.../dir1/dir2/... instead of just dir2/...